# Get transcript of youtube video

Tags: excel, vba, youtube, screen-scraping

I am trying to get the transcript of a video on YouTube but I am stuck
here's what I have

```
Sub ANew()
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument, ie As Object, p As Integer, i As Integer
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        
            .Navigate "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkzK1nfWoeA"
            Do: DoEvents: Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Set doc = ie.document
            
            While ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Debug.Print doc.querySelectorAll("div .ytd-transcript-body-renderer")(1).innerHTML
            

        ie.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

I got error at this line `Debug.Print doc.querySelectorAll("div .ytd-transcript-body-renderer")(1).innerHTML`. I don't know why this fails.

Comment: Where's `Next p`?

Comment: I removed the loop as this is no related to the code.

Comment: When I looked at the source for the website, there just aren't any elements with the `ytd-transcript-body-renderer` css class?

Comment: So this maybe different in each browser. I have inspected the page using Chrome not IE in fact as IE is corrupted for using developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as for Python but hopes to find a solution using VBA

```
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
import json
import pandas

data = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript('CkzK1nfWoeA')
with open('Transcript.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
pandas.read_json("Transcript.json").to_excel("Output.xlsx")
```